# What is the point of making RxBleClient non-static?

Tags: android, rxandroidble

In the RxAndroidBle sample application, the Application class is:

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application
    private RxBleClient rxBleClient;
    /**
     * In practise you will use some kind of dependency injection pattern.
     */
    public static RxBleClient getRxBleClient(Context context) {
        SampleApplication application = (SampleApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        return application.rxBleClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        rxBleClient = RxBleClient.create(this);
        RxBleClient.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.DEBUG);
    }
}
```

Since we are guaranteed that there will only be one instance of `Application`, and we only want one instance of `RxBleClient`, isn't it simpler to write:

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {

    private static RxBleClient rxBleClient;
    public static RxBleClient getRxBleClient() {
        return rxBleClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        rxBleClient = RxBleClient.create(this);
        RxBleClient.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.DEBUG);
    }
}
```

What is the benefit of the more complex approach? 
And what is meant by "some kind of dependency injection pattern"? Could we see an example? Again, what is the benefit?

Comment: The first would be more testable than the second

Comment: Why would it be more testable? Do you mean by injecting some kind of mock RxBleClient?

Comment: Yes, kind of it

Answer (score 1):

As Marcos Vasconcelos said, the first approach could be slightly easier to test though it is not a good design anyway.

[Dependency injection](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DependencyInjection/article.html) is a way to obtain a testable code which one could throughly test by (for instance) providing (mocked) dependencies at the construction time.

To see examples of dependency injection you can go to the [sources of `RxAndroidBle`](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) and check out how the classes are designed.

An example could be [`RxBleConnectionImpl` class](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble/internal/connection/RxBleConnectionImpl.java) which has quite a lot of dependencies that are injected. Thanks to that it was possible to create [extensive test suite](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/test/groovy/com/polidea/rxandroidble/internal/connection/RxBleConnectionTest.groovy) for it.

`RxAndroidBle` sample application was written as a sample that is easy to comprehend. It does not necessarily follows the best patterns as these are not always easy to follow. The main goal of the sample is to show the usage of the library API.